# Move jira issue types between branches

Tags: svn, teamcity, jira

I am looking out for a way to move issue types with code files from dev trunk to uat branch and then to prod branch. Can this be done with Jira? I dont want to do this manually in SVN

Integrating SVN and Teamcity with Jira.

Answer (score 0):

Jira is an issue tracking tool. I'm not sure why you have code files attached to an issue tracking tool.

You should be using a source code repo like SVN (which you are) for your code.

If you want to move your code from one branch to another, that should be done in your repo, not in jira.

JIra has no idea about your branching or deployment strategy.

If you want to mirror this, i.e to show where in the deployment pipeline a certain issue is, you can use Jira workflows. But this is done separately to the code.